# xs:any with all optional elements in xs:sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am working on XSD where I need to have xs:any at the end of a xs:sequence. All the previous elements in the sequence need to optional hence minOccurs="0". The following snippet gives me "cos-nonambig:  makes the content model non-deterministic against . Possible causes: name equality, overlapping occurrence or substitution groups." error

```
<xs:complexType name="nutritionData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="attributeList" type="attributeList" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="nutritionFactsList" type="nutritionFactsList" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ingredients" type="ingredientData" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Any workarounds ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an XSD 1.1 processor, this content model is no longer an error: the explicit element particles take priority over the wildcard particle in resolving the ambiguity. You can also use options such as #notSibling to exclude elements from matching the wildcard if they match any of the explicit element names in the content model.

In XSD 1.0 your only option, I think, is to force elements matching the wildcard to be in a different namespace.